# Join in DB::raw() laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4

I have 3 tables in my database :

```html
reponse[id,nomRep,#envoi_id]
envoi[id,#projet_id,#quest_id]
projet[id,nomProjet]
```

What i want to do is to get the **name of my project** using the code below:

```html
 $days = Input::get('days', 7);
                  $range = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays($days);
            $chartt = DB::table('reponse')
                ->where('created_at', '>=', $range)
                ->groupBy('value')
                
                ->remember(1440)
                ->get([
                    DB::raw('envoi_id as nomProjet')// here where i want to get the name of my project,
                    DB::raw('etatSatisfaction as value')
                    
                ]);

            return $chartt;
```

Any help please?

Comment: any help pleaaase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer i found it by my self, mybe someone need it:

```html
  DB::raw(' (SELECT p.nom FROM projet p,ligneenvoi l WHERE rep.ligneenvoi_id=l.id AND l.projet_id=p.id) AS nomProjet ') ,
```